# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer in view forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, apartment-gem

I am working on configuring the apartment gem for my rails app to give users the functionality to create subdomains. I have a nested form and when attempting to access "accounts/new" I am getting the following error:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer in view forms
```

**accounts/new.html.erb**

```
<div>
   </div>
    <h2>Create an Account</h2>

<%= form_for @account do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :owner do |o| %>
      <%= form_for o, :email do %>
        <%= o.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
      <% end %>
     <%= form_for o, :password do %>
        <%= o.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
      <% end %>
     <%= form_for o, :password_confirmation do %>
        <%= o.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>

    <%= form_for f, :subdomain do %>
      <div class="input-group">
      <%= f.text_field :subdomain, class: 'form-control' %>
        <span class="input-group-addon">.scrumteam.com</span>
      </div>
      <% end %>
     <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**accounts_controller.rb**

```
private 
      def account_params
        params.require(:account).permit(:subdomain, :owner_attributes => [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting multiple forms into each other which is not supported in HTML:
See this question for more details: [Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

These `form_for` lines look invalid in particular:

```
<%= form_for o, :field_name do %>
```

Here, `o` is a special `FormBuilder` object which should not be fed to `form_for`. Try this instead:

```
<%= f.fields_for :owner do |o| %>
  <%= o.fields_for :email do %>
```

Unlike `form_for`, it *is* possible to nest `fields_for` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your route problem, but `form_for` creates an actual `form` tag in html. You only need (and should have) 1, the `fields_for` allows you to switch the form helpers to a different object, but you don't need to call `form_for` again within it. If you're just trying to group your form fields, you can just add some divs and/or labels.